# How to pass a row field value to 'enableCellEdit' attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In Angular UI-Grid table, I have one date column (referenceDate) which I want to enable/disable edit based of a flag called '**allowed**' which is part of the row value.

How to pass this row value in 'enableCellEdit' attribute ?

Here is my code fragment.
I tried with 'row.entity.allowed' but it did not worked. And got error 
**Error: row is not defined**

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [ 
    {
        field : "referenceDate", width : "15%", enableCellEdit: row.entity.allowed, type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"',
    }, 
    {
        field : "manuallyUpdated", width : "10%", cellEditableCondition: false, cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.manuallyUpdated" disabled="true" style="zoom:1.5" >'
    }
];
```

**JSON data**

```
{
    "referenceDate": "2015-09-30",
    "allowed": true,
    "manuallyUpdated": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are not able to access the external scope when setting a value for `enableCellEdit`.
You should make use of `cellEditableCondition` and pass it a function like this -

```
function($scope){
  return $scope.row.entity.allowed;
}
```

From the docs :

> If specified, either a value or function evaluated before editing
>   cell. If falsy, then editing of cell is not allowed.